# Github Actions - Unable to get called / checkout reusable workflow's repository

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-reusable-workflows

Note: Both the caller and called reusable repo are public and their permissions are correctly set.

Below is my caller repo `actions_param` workflow [`test.yml`](https://github.com/knowyrtech/actions_param/blob/main/.github/workflows/test.yml):

```
name: TEST  main xml read

on:
  push:
    branches: main
    
jobs:
  inside_actionyml:
    uses: knowyrtech/betech/.github/workflows/extractxmldata.yml@feature365
    with:
      xml_Path: 'D:\myxl\setparam.xml'
      key_name: 'app_name'
```

As you can see it calls `betech`'s `extractxmldata.yml` from branch `feature365`.

This workflow will help get values from xml given the key by invoking `xml-functions.ps1`.

```
name: Read XML

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
        xml_Path:
          required: true
          default: ''
          type: string
        key_name:
          required: true
          default: ''
          type: string      
  
jobs: 
  Extract-keys:
    runs-on: 'windows-latest'
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Get present dir
        run: |
          Get-Location

      - name: List dir
        run: |
          dir   

      - name: Call power shell for extract XML values
        run: |
          set-location "${{ github.workspace }}\betech\scripts"
          ./xml-functions.ps1 "${{ inputs.xml_Path }}" "${{ inputs.key_name }}"
```

`xml-functions.ps1` is placed under the repo's scripts folder as you may see [here](https://github.com/knowyrtech/betech/blob/feature365/scripts/xml-functions.ps1).

The called workflow calls the reusable workflow however the reusable workflow does not find the reusable repo and its file `xml-functions.ps1` and throws an error as seen in the snapshot below:

[image: error]

```
Run set-location "D:\a\actions_param\actions_param\betech\scripts"
Set-Location: D:\a\_temp\0e075a8f-0439-43fc-9c45-1397748c0d29.ps1:2
Line |
   2 |  set-location "D:\a\actions_param\actions_param\betech\scripts"
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot find path 'D:\a\actions_param\actions_param\betech\scripts' because it does not exist.

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I tried the same on local Windows runner too and observed that the reusable repo `betech` does not get checkout [downloaded] at the runner at all and hence it fails to find `xml-functions.ps1`.

All I m concerned and need help is how to get `xml-functions.ps1` looked up and called.

Comment: IIUC, you expect a reusable workflow checkout step to checkout its own repo instead of the repo it's being run from?

Comment: I understood the `uses:` in the calling repo Will checkout the called repo `xml-functions.ps1` Will I have to explicitly checkout the reusable called repo `betech` in the calling repo? I have not seen this as a requirement and I m new to github so not sure.

Comment: The script you're using is not there as part of the workflow itself so it does not exist there without an explicit checkout. So, yes, you need to do something to have it there e.g. checkout or download it via its direct link (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/knowyrtech/betech/main/scripts/xml-functions.ps1).

Comment: Apart from that, your [reusable workflow](https://github.com/knowyrtech/betech/blob/feature365/.github/workflows/extractxmldata.yml) has some linting issues. Lint it with https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/.

Comment: @Azeem linting issue has now been fixed. Checking how and where to checkout so to be able to find the `ps1` file

Comment: Good. You may directly add that under `run` section if you don't have to worry about its logistics at all.

Comment: i added the remote repo checkout but it does not seem to have been downloaded in `workspace` directory. https://github.com/knowyrtech/actions_param/edit/main/.github/workflows/test.yml

Comment: Your checkout is nested and is in the first job. But, the workflow that needs it is in the second job. Jobs are run on different runners. So, it won't work.

Comment: @Azeem i added explicit checkout as suggested with the name `      - name: Checkout remote repository suggested by stack user @Azeem` in the called workflow file https://github.com/knowyrtech/betech/edit/feature365/.github/workflows/extractxmldata.yml. Now the `ps1` file seems to be found. I will now work on collecting and displaying return values from the `ps1` function. Thank you for your help and if u can post the answer

Comment: Good. This [checkout](https://github.com/knowyrtech/actions_param/blob/900116619e1c735b253d2e1b4a07b8202a12c3a5/.github/workflows/test.yml#L17-L22) step is redundant now. You may remove it.

Comment: The current checkout dumps `scripts` folder in `workspace` but I wish to get it under the repo i.e `workspace\<repo-name>\scripts\xml-functions.ps1`.  I changed `          path: "${{ github.workspace }}\betech"` while checkout but it fails. I don't want to create `betech` folder explicitly but need it auto-created like how `git clone` does.

Comment: Remove `path` and it'll be nested. See https://github.com/actions/checkout for such examples.

Comment: @Azeem i removed the `path` but i still do not see repo folder created ...see here: https://github.com/knowyrtech/betech/blob/feature365/.github/workflows/extractxmldata.yml

Comment: It should be under your first checked out repo i.e. `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE/actions_param/actions_param/betech`. Check the nested directories with `dir` or `tree` command (if available).

Comment: i removed `path` from test.yml first checkout too but don't see the `betech` repo folder created. Here: https://github.com/knowyrtech/actions_param/actions/runs/5021694199/jobs/9004334220. Basically I need the `.ps1` under `"${{ github.workspace }}\betech\scripts"`

Comment: Looks like the intermediate `betech` is [not being created](https://github.com/knowyrtech/actions_param/actions/runs/5021694199/jobs/9004334220#step:8:6). Try `path: "${{ github.workspace }}/actions_param/betech`.

Comment: @Azeem this worked `          path: "${{ github.workspace }}/betech"`

Comment: So, finally, you got it to work? If yes, you may self-answer this with all the details. BTW, instead of making it a reusable workflow, you could make a [composite](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action) action for better reusability. All the best!